# jQuery append element and replace selected row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I to change the elements of the selected row?
[image]

When my combo box is changed, I want to check the value of the combo. If the value of "**Gender**" is chosen, then I would like to replace the element "**Input Value Ke-3**" textbox value into :

```
<select id="data3" name="data3[]">
     <option value="man" selected >Man</option>
     <option value="woman">Woman</option>
</select>
```

Whether this can be done using $.(selector).html() ?

My code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    MyLogic();
});

function MyLogic(){
  $(".addCF").click(function(){
      $("#customFields").append(
          '<tr>'
            + '<td>'
                    + '<select class="tabelBaru" id="data1" name="data1[]">'
                            + '<option value="email" selected >Email</option>'
                            + '<option value="gender">Gender</option>'
                            + '<option value="age">Age</option>'
                    + '</select>&nbsp;'
            + '</td>'
            + '<td>'
                + '<input type="text" id="data2" name="data2[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value Ke-2" />'
            + '</td>'
            + '<td>'
                + '<input type="text" id="data3" name="data3[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value Ke-3" />'
            + '</td>'
            + '<td>'
                + '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a>'
            + '</td>'
        + '</tr>'
      );
  });

    $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    }); 

    $(document.body).on('change', '.tabelBaru', function() {
        var nilai = $(this).val();
        if(nilai=='email'){
           $("#data3").html('Change another input type here...');
        }
    });
}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: so what happens if someone uses the combo in the row above? do you still plan to create a select with an id of data3?

Comment: ID may be more dynamic? I am still in the learning stage using javascript .. Maybe you could give a little help to me in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all do not use duplicate ids. Use classes instead.

Add change handler like this:

```
$("#customFields").on('change', '.tabelBaru', function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            nilai = $this.val();
        console.log(nilai);
        if(nilai=='gender'){
           $this.closest("tr").find(".data3").replaceWith('<select name="data3[]" class="data3">     <option value="man" selected >Man</option>     <option value="woman">Woman</option></select>'); //creating select
        }
        else {
            $this.closest("tr").find(".data3").replaceWith('<input type="text" name="data3[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value Ke-3" class="data3"/>'); 
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tbt93/